# Mac Terminal Keeps Exiting

Tags: terminal

I used the exit command once in terminal and it gave me the following message:

```
Last login: Tue Jun 20 09:18:45 on ttys005

Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

Now every time I try to open a new window/tab it displays the same message and does not allow me to type anything else into the shell. It seems that the exit command is being run automatically on login. How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you using zsh or bash?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the directory `~/.zsh-sessions`.

You can then disable the ZSH session nonsense by setting `SHELL_SESSIONS_DISABLE=1` in `~/.zshenv`.

Comment: Why would a saved session lead to a blocked shell on reload?